# Accessing controls in newly added listview row WPF C#

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a listview in WPF and C# that uses an ObservableCollection to populate the data. When a certain event is fired, I call a function to insert a new row into the collection. I then need to access the controls in that row.

The problem i am having is that after i insert the row, and I try to loop through the listview rows, this row is displaying as null in my loop.

```
       if (addNewNote)
        {

            _resultsCollection.Insert(0, new ResultsData
            {
                Notes = "Data to Insert",
                // ... rest of fields

            });

        } // end if (addNewNote)

        for (int currRowIndex = 0; currRowIndex < this.ResultsList.Items.Count; currRowIndex++)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem currRow =
                (System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem)this.ResultsList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(currRowIndex);

            if (currRow != null)
            {
                System.Windows.Controls.TextBox tb = FindByName("EditNotesTextBox", currRow) as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;

        // do stuff with controls ...
            }
        }
```

Here currRow is always null, when the currRowIndex is zero.

This should not be the case, because i have just added it. Is it because I am trying to access it in the same function where I insert it, and the listview has not yet been updated? I am able to access every other row in the listview. Is there a better solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to newly added item to be accessible first the container for that item (UI) needs to be generated by `ItemContainerGenrator`. The generation is done on the same (UI) thread, so you cannot access containers right after you have added an item.

You can subscribe to `ResultsList.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged` event and in the event handler check if the status is `GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated` then you can obtain the container.

```
ResultsList.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += OnGeneratorStatusChanged;

...

private void OnGeneratorStatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
        // Access containers for newly added items
    }        
}
```

Please refer to [this article](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/07/20/itemscontrol-g-is-for-generator/) by Dr.WPF that describes how it works in detail.

Comment: sorry the delayed response, this worked brilliantly for me, thank you!